# Re-replication on region failover in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Because I'd like to use Multi-DC deployments features, I found that there is a case that the number of replicas can’t be ensured if I modify placement information and all nodes fail in one zone.

There are three zones and I created two nodes in each zone. I tested YugabyteDB 2.11.1.0
I modify placement info to control minimum replicas in each region.

```
yb-admin \
  -master_addresses ${MASTER_IPADDRS} \
  modify_placement_info \
  cloud1.region-a.region-a-1,cloud1.region-b.region-b-1,cloud1.region-c.region-c-1 3
```

What happens if all nodes in region-a-1 fail?

```
kill -kill ${YB-Tserver processes in region-a-1}
```

Although my expectation is that new replicas will be created in region-b-1 or region-c-1.
Should they be created?

The replication factor is 3, but each tablet has only 2 replicas in the YugabyteDB cluster.

Is the above behavior expected or am I missing something? It seems that the maximum replicas in each region is configured to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The `modify_placement_info` command ensures how many minimum & exact replicas of each tablet we want in that placement block. This command is used to configure the number of replicas in multi-region deployments. In your case, with replication_factor=3, you’ll want 1 replica in each region. So even in the case of losing a single region, you can maintain availability for writes & reads. But, if you lose a particular region, new replicas will not be created in the remaining regions. You need to bring up the region that has failed.

The other option would be to have replication_factor=5, and then you can keep 2 regions with 2 replicas each and another region with 1 replica like below:

```
$ ./bin/yb-admin \
    -master_addresses $MASTER_RPC_ADDRS \
    modify_placement_info  \
    aws.us-west.us-west-2a:2,aws.us-west.us-west-2b:2,aws.us-west.us-west-2c 5
```

This will place a minimum of:

```
2 replicas in aws.us-west.us-west-2a
2 replicas in aws.us-west.us-west-2b
1 replica in aws.us-west.us-west-2c
```

See [the doc page](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-admin/#modify-placement-info) of the command for more information.